# In Intellij / Android Studio, how do I change the diff against branch for the diff gutter column?

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, how do I change the "diff against" branch that the diff gutter column uses?

It looks like by default, it shows the diff of my local changes against the my last commit. But I want to diff against the master branch, not the last commit of the branch I am currently working on.

For example, I am in a local feature-branch, but I want the diff to be against local master.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The diff gutter always shows your local changes (same as the Changes view).